# Laravel PHP Traits with models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a PHP trait that I will use in any model that can do a certain set of actions. For example one of these actions is completion where completed_at is marked with a timestamp.

The trait method is:

```
/**
 * @return $this
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function markCompleted(){
    if($this->canDoAction('complete')){
        $this->completed_at = Carbon::now();
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In my controller I am calling this on a model that can do this action like below.

```
$app->markCompleted()->save();
```

The $app when I view its contents it is not null.

Running this command returns an error like

```
local.ERROR: Call to a member function save() on null
```

Wouldn't $this represent the model that uses this trait?

Comment: If the condition doesn't meet then `null` will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation on what The Alpha said.

```
/**
 * @return $this
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function markCompleted(){
    if($this->canDoAction('complete')){
        $this->completed_at = Carbon::now();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

This way you always return a model, and you can chain other functions before the save is performed if you needed.

Answer (score 0):

If the condition doesn't meet then `null` will be returned, so instead of calling the `save` separately, do that inside that method, for example:

```
public function markCompleted()
{
    if ($this->canDoAction('complete')) {
        $this->completed_at = Carbon::now();
        return $this->save(); // true/false
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
$app->markCompleted();
```

The way way, you coded, the `save` method will be called even if the condition doesn't match and that's a side effect.